# Plot help with axes coordinates

Tags: plotting

```
Plot[{4 - 2 y, (5 + y)/3}, {y, 1, 10}]
```

[image: graph]

How do I make Mathematica tell me the coordinates for cuts with the y-axis, other than just looking at it?

Comment: Have a look at the documentation for `Solve`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use the `MeshFunctions` option to get the intercepts as follows:

```
Plot[{4 - 2 y, (5 + y)/3}, {y, -10, 10},
      MeshFunctions -> {#2 &}, Mesh -> {{0.}},  MeshStyle -> PointSize[Large]]
```

[image]

```
Plot[{4 - 2 y, (5 + y)/3}, {y, -10, 10},
      MeshFunctions -> {#1 &}, Mesh -> {{0.}},  MeshStyle -> PointSize[Large]]
```

[image]

Comment: I'm a little bit disappointed that you got the acceptance :)

Comment: @eldo, i know the feeling :)

Answer (score 2):

```
fun = {4 - 2 y, (5 + y) / 3};

p = Flatten @ Map[Solve[# == 0, y] &, fun] /. Rule[_, a_] :> a
```

> {2, -5}

```
Plot[fun, {y, -10, 10},
 Epilog -> {PointSize@0.02, Point[{#, 0}] & /@ p},
 FrameTicks -> {p, Automatic},
 FrameTicksStyle -> 12,
 GridLines -> {p, {0}},
 ImageSize -> 500,
 PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
```

[image]